# Changing dataset for Random Forest code cause abnormal results

Tags: python, dataset, random-forest

I use the randomforest code based on [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/implement-random-forest-scratch-python/).
Here it is (skip over to the end to see the question):

```
# Select the best split point for a dataset
def get_split(dataset, n_features):
    class_values = list(set(row[-1] for row in dataset))
    b_index, b_value, b_score, b_groups = 999, 999, 999, None
    features = list()
    while len(features) < n_features:
        index = randrange(len(dataset[0])-1)
        if index not in features:
            features.append(index)
    for index in features:
        for row in dataset:
            groups = test_split(index, row[index], dataset)
            gini = gini_index(groups, class_values)
            if gini < b_score:
                b_index, b_value, b_score, b_groups = index, row[index], gini, groups
    return {'index':b_index, 'value':b_value, 'groups':b_groups}


# Random Forest Algorithm on Sonar Dataset
from random import seed
from random import randrange
from csv import reader
from math import sqrt


# Load a CSV file
def load_csv(filename):
    dataset = list()
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        csv_reader = reader(file)
        for row in csv_reader:
            if not row:
                continue
            dataset.append(row)
    return dataset


# Convert string column to float
def str_column_to_float(dataset, column):
    for row in dataset:
        row[column] = float(row[column].strip())


# Convert string column to integer
def str_column_to_int(dataset, column):
    class_values = [row[column] for row in dataset]
    unique = set(class_values)
    lookup = dict()
    for i, value in enumerate(unique):
        lookup[value] = i
    for row in dataset:
        row[column] = lookup[row[column]]
    return lookup


# Split a dataset into k folds
def cross_validation_split(dataset, n_folds):
    dataset_split = list()
    dataset_copy = list(dataset)
    fold_size = int(len(dataset) / n_folds)
    for i in range(n_folds):
        fold = list()
        while len(fold) < fold_size:
            index = randrange(len(dataset_copy))
            fold.append(dataset_copy.pop(index))
        dataset_split.append(fold)
    return dataset_split


# Calculate accuracy percentage
def accuracy_metric(actual, predicted):
    correct = 0
    for i in range(len(actual)):
        if actual[i] == predicted[i]:
            correct += 1
    return correct / float(len(actual)) * 100.0


# Evaluate an algorithm using a cross validation split
def evaluate_algorithm(dataset, algorithm, n_folds, *args):
    folds = cross_validation_split(dataset, n_folds)
    scores = list()
    for fold in folds:
        train_set = list(folds)
        train_set.remove(fold)
        train_set = sum(train_set, [])
        test_set = list()
        for row in fold:
            row_copy = list(row)
            test_set.append(row_copy)
            row_copy[-1] = None
        predicted = algorithm(train_set, test_set, *args)
        actual = [row[-1] for row in fold]
        accuracy = accuracy_metric(actual, predicted)
        scores.append(accuracy)
    return scores


# Split a dataset based on an attribute and an attribute value
def test_split(index, value, dataset):
    left, right = list(), list()
    for row in dataset:
        if row[index] < value:
            left.append(row)
        else:
            right.append(row)
    return left, right


# Calculate the Gini index for a split dataset
def gini_index(groups, classes):
    # count all samples at split point
    n_instances = float(sum([len(group) for group in groups]))
    # sum weighted Gini index for each group
    gini = 0.0
    for group in groups:
        size = float(len(group))
        # avoid divide by zero
        if size == 0:
            continue
        score = 0.0
        # score the group based on the score for each class
        for class_val in classes:
            p = [row[-1] for row in group].count(class_val) / size
            score += p * p
        # weight the group score by its relative size
        gini += (1.0 - score) * (size / n_instances)
    return gini


# Select the best split point for a dataset
def get_split(dataset, n_features):
    class_values = list(set(row[-1] for row in dataset))
    b_index, b_value, b_score, b_groups = 999, 999, 999, None
    features = list()
    while len(features) < n_features:
        index = randrange(len(dataset[0]) - 1)
        if index not in features:
            features.append(index)
    for index in features:
        for row in dataset:
            groups = test_split(index, row[index], dataset)
            gini = gini_index(groups, class_values)
            if gini < b_score:
                b_index, b_value, b_score, b_groups = index, row[index], gini, groups
    return {'index': b_index, 'value': b_value, 'groups': b_groups}


# Create a terminal node value
def to_terminal(group):
    outcomes = [row[-1] for row in group]
    return max(set(outcomes), key=outcomes.count)


# Create child splits for a node or make terminal
def split(node, max_depth, min_size, n_features, depth):
    left, right = node['groups']
    del (node['groups'])
    # check for a no split
    if not left or not right:
        node['left'] = node['right'] = to_terminal(left + right)
        return
    # check for max depth
    if depth >= max_depth:
        node['left'], node['right'] = to_terminal(left), to_terminal(right)
        return
    # process left child
    if len(left) <= min_size:
        node['left'] = to_terminal(left)
    else:
        node['left'] = get_split(left, n_features)
        split(node['left'], max_depth, min_size, n_features, depth + 1)
    # process right child
    if len(right) <= min_size:
        node['right'] = to_terminal(right)
    else:
        node['right'] = get_split(right, n_features)
        split(node['right'], max_depth, min_size, n_features, depth + 1)


# Build a decision tree
def build_tree(train, max_depth, min_size, n_features):
    root = get_split(train, n_features)
    split(root, max_depth, min_size, n_features, 1)
    return root


# Make a prediction with a decision tree
def predict(node, row):
    if row[node['index']] < node['value']:
        if isinstance(node['left'], dict):
            return predict(node['left'], row)
        else:
            return node['left']
    else:
        if isinstance(node['right'], dict):
            return predict(node['right'], row)
        else:
            return node['right']


# Create a random subsample from the dataset with replacement
def subsample(dataset, ratio):
    sample = list()
    n_sample = round(len(dataset) * ratio)
    while len(sample) < n_sample:
        index = randrange(len(dataset))
        sample.append(dataset[index])
    return sample


# Make a prediction with a list of bagged trees
def bagging_predict(trees, row):
    predictions = [predict(tree, row) for tree in trees]
    return max(set(predictions), key=predictions.count)


# Random Forest Algorithm
def random_forest(train, test, max_depth, min_size, sample_size, n_trees, n_features):
    trees = list()
    for i in range(n_trees):
        sample = subsample(train, sample_size)
        tree = build_tree(sample, max_depth, min_size, n_features)
        trees.append(tree)
    predictions = [bagging_predict(trees, row) for row in test]
    return (predictions)
```

In order to generalize it so it will be run for every dataset I wrote the following:

```
import pandas as pd
file_path ='http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/undocumented/connectionist-bench/sonar/sonar.all-data'
dataset2 =pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, sep=',')
v = dataset2.values

f = pd.factorize(v.ravel())[0].reshape(v.shape)

dataset1 = pd.DataFrame(f)
df = dataset1.astype('str')

dataset = df.values.tolist()
target_index = 60
for i in range(0, len(dataset[0])):
        if i != target_index:
            str_column_to_float(dataset, i)
# convert class column to integers
str_column_to_int(dataset, target_index)
n_folds = 5
max_depth = 10
min_size = 1
sample_size = 1.0
n_features = int(sqrt(len(dataset[0]) - 1))


for n_trees in [5]:
    scores = evaluate_algorithm(dataset, random_forest, n_folds, max_depth, min_size, sample_size, n_trees, n_features)
    print('Trees: %d' % n_trees)
    print('Scores: %s' % scores)
    print('Mean Accuracy: %.3f%%' % (sum(scores) / float(len(scores))))
```

The above-mentioned code works great for SONAR dataset. It structure is:

```
0.0200,0.0371,0.0428,0.0207,0.0954,0.0986,0.1539,0.1601,0.3109,0.2111,0.1609,0.1582,0.2238,0.0645,0.0660,0.2273,0.3100,0.2999,0.5078,0.4797,0.5783,0.5071,0.4328,0.5550,0.6711,0.6415,0.7104,0.8080,0.6791,0.3857,0.1307,0.2604,0.5121,0.7547,0.8537,0.8507,0.6692,0.6097,0.4943,0.2744,0.0510,0.2834,0.2825,0.4256,0.2641,0.1386,0.1051,0.1343,0.0383,0.0324,0.0232,0.0027,0.0065,0.0159,0.0072,0.0167,0.0180,0.0084,0.0090,0.0032,R
0.0453,0.0523,0.0843,0.0689,0.1183,0.2583,0.2156,0.3481,0.3337,0.2872,0.4918,0.6552,0.6919,0.7797,0.7464,0.9444,1.0000,0.8874,0.8024,0.7818,0.5212,0.4052,0.3957,0.3914,0.3250,0.3200,0.3271,0.2767,0.4423,0.2028,0.3788,0.2947,0.1984,0.2341,0.1306,0.4182,0.3835,0.1057,0.1840,0.1970,0.1674,0.0583,0.1401,0.1628,0.0621,0.0203,0.0530,0.0742,0.0409,0.0061,0.0125,0.0084,0.0089,0.0048,0.0094,0.0191,0.0140,0.0049,0.0052,0.0044,R
```

These are the results (that seems OK):

```
Trees: 5
Scores: [100.0, 95.1219512195122, 100.0, 97.5609756097561, 100.0]
Mean Accuracy: 98.537%
```

When I change the dataset into breast-cancer-wisconsin:

```
842302,M,17.99,10.38,122.8,1001,0.1184,0.2776,0.3001,0.1471,0.2419,0.07871,1.095,0.9053,8.589,153.4,0.006399,0.04904,0.05373,0.01587,0.03003,0.006193,25.38,17.33,184.6,2019,0.1622,0.6656,0.7119,0.2654,0.4601,0.1189
842517,M,20.57,17.77,132.9,1326,0.08474,0.07864,0.0869,0.07017,0.1812,0.05667,0.5435,0.7339,3.398,74.08,0.005225,0.01308,0.0186,0.0134,0.01389,0.003532,24.99,23.41,158.8,1956,0.1238,0.1866,0.2416,0.186,0.275,0.08902
```

I change the relevant code into:

```
import pandas as pd
file_path ='https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/breast-cancer-wisconsin/wdbc.data'
dataset2 =pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, sep=',')
v = dataset2.values

f = pd.factorize(v.ravel())[0].reshape(v.shape)

dataset1 = pd.DataFrame(f)
df = dataset1.astype('str')

dataset = df.values.tolist()
target_index = 1 ## <----
for i in range(0, len(dataset[0])):
        if i != target_index:
            str_column_to_float(dataset, i)
# convert class column to integers
str_column_to_int(dataset, target_index)
n_folds = 5
max_depth = 10
min_size = 1
sample_size = 1.0
n_features = int(sqrt(len(dataset[0]) - 1))


for n_trees in [5]:
    scores = evaluate_algorithm(dataset, random_forest, n_folds, max_depth, min_size, sample_size, n_trees, n_features)
    print('Trees: %d' % n_trees)
    print('Scores: %s' % scores)
    print('Mean Accuracy: %.3f%%' % (sum(scores) / float(len(scores))))
```

I runs for a very long time and the results seems wrong:

```
Trees: 5
Scores: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8849557522123894, 0.0]
Mean Accuracy: 0.177%
```

Comment: Did you try repeated runs? The word **random** in the  *Random Forests* method name are there for a reason... How about trying a few runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the nature of Random Forest method is *highly* data-dependent and the method is sensitive both to the random seed and noise in the data. Therefore,  changing the dataset to a different one with a different characteristics of noise and class separability might be producing mediocre results even when it worked perfectly for another dataset.

There is also a factor of pure chance in the *random* part of the method... Hence, any results achieved should be repeated for validation. It may be just a bad luck of this particular run although your results suggest that the method is just ill-suited for the dataset.

If you really need to dive into the topic of Random Forest I would suggest a thorough summary in (freely available) [Understanding Random Forests: From Theory to Practice](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.7502.pdf) by Gilles Louppe.

There is also an interesting discussion on outliers' sensitivity of the method on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/187200/how-are-random-forests-not-sensitive-to-outliers) forum.

Comment: Thanks @sophros, as can be seen from the results of breast-cancer-wisconsin dataset: 4 out of the 5 folds yields 0% of accuracy whereas the fifth yields 88.5% something looks fishy!